# How to encode audio with ffmpeg library?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to remake the `doc/examples/transcoding.c` so that in encodes opus audio. How can I do that?

This is what I have right now:

```
            encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_OPUS);

            if (!encoder) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Necessary encoder not found\n");
                return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
            }
            enc_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
            if (!enc_ctx) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to allocate the encoder context\n");
                return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            }

            enc_ctx->thread_count = 1;


            /* enc_ctx->sample_rate = dec_ctx->sample_rate; */
            enc_ctx->sample_rate = 48000;

            /* enc_ctx->channel_layout = dec_ctx->channel_layout; */
            enc_ctx->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO;


            enc_ctx->channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(enc_ctx->channel_layout);
            /* take first format from list of supported formats */
            enc_ctx->sample_fmt = encoder->sample_fmts[0];
            enc_ctx->time_base = (AVRational){1, enc_ctx->sample_rate};

            enc_ctx->bit_rate = 32000;
```

Should I convert to 48000 Hz and to mono with filters, or encoder will figure it out by itself?

How to copy audio from one packet to another? (It looks like each packet should contain exactly 20ms of audio, that's 960 samples). This page https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFrame.html says something about `AVFrame.buf`, how to copy all samples from there?

```
[libopus @ 02ec1d60] more samples than frame size (avcodec_encode_audio2)
```

Comment: You should post where you call `avcodec_encode_audio2`.

Comment: This answer is outdated, I learned about the existance of `swr_convert`. Here is the new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379933/how-to-scale-and-mux-audio